# Html, Css Background Not Showing

Tags: html, image, css, styles

This is probably a really stupid question, but my background for my nav div wont show, I really don't know the problem to this, the css file is linked and working with some elements.

**Image Properties**
Size: 10kb
-Bit Depth: 32
-Dimensions: W:300 H:190
-File Type: png
-Name: Nav_Background

**What it needs to do**
 http://prntscr.com/l89oq0

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

   <title>Portfolio Template</title>

   <meta name="author" content="name">
   <meta name="description" content="description here">
   <meta name="keywords" content="keywords,here">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>

   <div class="nav">

   </div>

   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```
                /*----------Global----------*/
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                outline: 0;
                font-size: 100%;
                vertical-align: baseline;
                background: transparent;
            }

            .clearfix::after{
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: table;
            }
            html{
                font-family: circular std, sans-serif;
                font-weight: 100;
            }
            body{
                width: 100%;
                margin: auto;
                background: white; /*Replace with background image
                background-position: top;
                background-size: cover;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
            }

            /*----------Navigation----------*/
            .nav {
                background-image: url(images/Nav_Background.png);
                background-position: right top;
                background-size: 300px 191px;
                margin-top: 5px;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div class="nav">` (and if you are using a class named `nav` you should really be asking yourself if you should be using a `<nav>` element instead) has no content or anything else that would give it a height.

With no height, there are no pixels to paint the background on.

Comment: Awsome thanks now it works, btw ima keep using divs instead. xD